# How do you pass a slice to function list in go?

Tags: go, slice

I want to pass some values to a (3rd party) function with a signature like this:

```
func Load(files ...string) error {
```

If I build up a slice of files like this:

```
var files []string
append(files, "...")
append(files, "...")
```

How do I pass my files slice to the function Load? This:

```
Load(files)
```

Results in this error:

> cannot use files (type []string) as type string in argument to Load

Comment: This was asked just 3 hours ago. You need to use `...` like this: `Load(files...)`.

Comment: There's absolutely no way I could have found that question and answer, but thanks, that is the correct answer